# Show dates, not timestamps on x-axis of Google Charts line chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Here is my function for drawing a line chart using the Google Charts API. The timestamps used for d1, d2, d3 and d4 are -

1/1/2006 00:00:00 to 1/1/2009 00:00:00

When I set breakpoints in the Chrome debugger d1-d4 show up as `Sun Jan 01 2006 06:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`, etc...

The granularity I required is 'days', I dont care about minutes/seconds. Anyway, that's another issue as I can't even get anything to render at the moment, I just get a blank page when using this function. What am I doing wrong?

```
function drawChart() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date();
    var d3 = new Date();
    var d4 = new Date();
    d1.setTime(1136095200*1000);
    d2.setTime(1167631200*1000);
    d3.setTime(1199167200*1000);
    d4.setTime(1230789600*1000);
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          [d1,  1000,      400],
          [d2,  1170,      460],
          [d3,  660,       1120],
          [d4,  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference):

> The type can be one of the following: 'string' 'number' 'boolean' 'date' 'datetime' 'timeofday'.

It's inferring the type as "datetime", since you're not explicitly declaring it. Try using `addColumn` to add it directly as just `date`.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
```